# Is this $parse:syntax error coming from my code or the angular library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The error message says: "Syntax Error: Token 'false' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [return] starting at [{4}]."

But the stacktrace in the browser console shows this:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=false&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=8&p3=returnNaNalse%3B&p4=false%3B
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Object.s.throwError (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:210:32)
    at Object.s.ast (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:202:296)
    at Object.rd.compile (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:211:406)
    at gc.parse (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:238:281)
    at http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:117:338
    at Object.compile (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:1)
    at Z (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:65:275)
    at O (http://localhost:34574/libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:235)
```

The stacktrace only makes references to angular.min.js and I'm not sure if this is because the error is really in the library file or if the error is somewhere else and just showing up in the library. If it's the latter, how do I debug this?

Comment: Looks like the error is somewhere else and just showing up in the angular file, I'm not sure about how to debug it still.

Comment: Its coming from your code... I am using the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js same angular script with no issues. Pretty sure this is a default error message for some sort of error in your angular app's configuration

Answer (score 0):

`$parse` is responsible for transforming expressions like {{obj[0]}} to javascript objects/functions.

This is quite usual type of error. It comes from your html template. Some expression has wrong syntax. I.e.:
`ng-class="{{'a' : a}"` will give same type of error.